# Tensorflow csv dataset usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I have a csv file with the following format and data:

```
ID  nr1 nr2 nr3 nr4 nr5 next_nr
1   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   2   3   4   5   6   7
3   3   4   5   6   7   8
4   4   5   6   7   8   9
5   5   6   7   8   9   10
6   6   7   8   9   10  11
7   7   8   9   10  11  12
8   8   9   10  11  12  13
9   9   10  11  12  13  14
10  10  11  12  13  14  15
```

So, there are 10 rows including my train data. And I want to use tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset to read the data. Here is the example code for reading it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ITERATOR_BATCH_SIZE = 2
NR_EPOCHS = 3

train1_path = 'train1_short.csv'

dataset = tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset(train1_path,
                                     [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32],
                                     header=True)

dataset = dataset.batch(ITERATOR_BATCH_SIZE)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    for i in range (NR_EPOCHS):
        print('\nepoch: ', i)
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        next_element = iterator.get_next()
        while True:            
            try:
              data_and_target = sess.run([next_element])
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
              break
            print("\n\n", data_and_target)
```

When I run this code, I expect the output to include 2 rows of data in each batch. But the data I get looks pretty strange. Here is the output from the first epoch:

```
epoch:  0


 [(array([1., 2.], dtype=float32), array([1., 2.], dtype=float32), array([2., 3.], dtype=float32), array([3., 4.], dtype=float32), array([4., 5.], dtype=float32), array([5., 6.], dtype=float32), array([6., 7.], dtype=float32))]


 [(array([3., 4.], dtype=float32), array([3., 4.], dtype=float32), array([4., 5.], dtype=float32), array([5., 6.], dtype=float32), array([6., 7.], dtype=float32), array([7., 8.], dtype=float32), array([8., 9.], dtype=float32))]


 [(array([5., 6.], dtype=float32), array([5., 6.], dtype=float32), array([6., 7.], dtype=float32), array([7., 8.], dtype=float32), array([8., 9.], dtype=float32), array([ 9., 10.], dtype=float32), array([10., 11.], dtype=float32))]


 [(array([7., 8.], dtype=float32), array([7., 8.], dtype=float32), array([8., 9.], dtype=float32), array([ 9., 10.], dtype=float32), array([10., 11.], dtype=float32), array([11., 12.], dtype=float32), array([12., 13.], dtype=float32))]


 [(array([ 9., 10.], dtype=float32), array([ 9., 10.], dtype=float32), array([10., 11.], dtype=float32), array([11., 12.], dtype=float32), array([12., 13.], dtype=float32), array([13., 14.], dtype=float32), array([14., 15.], dtype=float32))]
```

Instead, I would - for exmaple - expect the very first batch to like the following:

```
[(array([1., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6], dtype=float32), array([2., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.], dtype=float32)]
```

The issue might be very trivial but I just cannot see why it looks like this. Maybe a more experienced person in the field can see it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each record of the `CsvDatset` must be converted to a tensor. Let me know if this works for you:

```
dataset = tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset(train1_path,
                                     [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32],
                                     header=True, field_delim=' ')

dataset = dataset.map(lambda *x: tf.convert_to_tensor(x))
dataset = dataset.batch(ITERATOR_BATCH_SIZE)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range (NR_EPOCHS):
        print('\nepoch: ', i)
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        next_element = iterator.get_next()
        while True:            
            try:
              data_and_target = sess.run(next_element)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
              break
            print("\n\n", data_and_target)
```

For my test, I had to set the `field_delim` argument to get it to work.

Comment: This is soo good! Thank you, @MatthewScarpino! With a small difference, your code did not work in my case as it is. But I removed the field_delim=' ' parameter, and it worked perffectly fine. It might be related to the application you possible use for csv files, I don't know. But this answer perfectly answers the problem.

Comment: What does one do if not all types are `tf.float32`? For instance, I have a column of type `tf.string` and another of `tf.float32`. How do I appropriately adapt `tf.convert_to_tensor`?